# Train a torch model using one GPU and the shared memory

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu-shared-memory

I am new to training pytorch models
and on GPU
I have tried training it on windows, but was always use the dedicated memory (10GB) and does not utilise the shared memory
I have tried  enhancing its performance using multiprocessing, but I kept getting the error :
TypeError: cannot pickle 'module' object

The solution usually is to use num_wrokers =0 while loading the data
I actually use the multiprocessing after loading the data
And need only to utilise the shared memory

I am retraing meta-sr speaker verification code, specifically the training file:
https://github.com/seongmin-kye/meta-SR/blob/b4c1ea1728e33f7bbf7015c38f508f24594f3f88/train.py

I have edited the line 92 to use the shared GPU memory as the following
instead of:
`train(train_generator, model, objective, optimizer, n_episode, log_dir, scheduler)`
To:

```
    model.share_memory()
    p = mp.Process(target=train, args=(train_generator,model,objective, optimizer, n_episode, log_dir, scheduler))
    p.num_workers=0
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Please let me know if more information shall be added
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your code and your setup.

Comment: Edited, based on your recommendation, Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shared memory (part of RAM) can be used only if there are two GPUs in PC
and this case there was only one GPU